# Explicit Lie May structure on cosimplicial DG Lie algebras

Tags: simplicial-stuff, lie-algebras, homotopy-theory

In the paper "Homotopy Lie algebras", Schechtman and Hinich proved that any cosimplicial
differential graded Lie algebra has the structure of a 'Lie May algebra'.

If my understanding is right here, a Lie May algebra is just an uncommon term for Lie infinity algebra.

Now the question is, if there is any *explicit* construction of this Lie infinity 
algebra structure?

I mean, are there any explicit formulas that define the $k$-ary brackets of this
Lie $\infty$-algebra in terms of the cofaces/codegeneracies and the Lie bracket of the
underlying cosimplicial DG Lie algebra?

**Edit:** If this is unknown, then I would be thankful for ideas on how to proceed in an attempt to find these maps.

Comment: Why doesn't the proof answer your question?

Comment: The proof uses the Lie Eilenberg Zilber operad and doesn't make any
reference to the maps I'm after. If one can read the k-ary maps from the action of this operad on the cosimpl. DG Lie algebra, then this is
not at all obvious... At least to me.

Comment: The authors of the paper in question are Vladimir Hinich and Vadim Schechtman, and they are responsible for the name ``Lie May''.  My
only real connection with the paper is that I wrote its Math Review.
My recollection is that the L_{\infty} nomenclature came later.

Comment: I mixed it up... Replaced 'May' by 'Schechtman' as author. Sorry for that. 